# __doPostBack no me funciona en FireFox

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, .net, visual-studio-2017

Tengo el siguiente código que funciona perfecto en todos los navegadores menos en Firefox!!

Inserto dentro de un "div" lo siguiente desde el servidor al cargar la pagina:

```
<button runat="server" onClick='mifuncion();'>Start</button>
```

y el siguiente código en JavaScript en la pagina HTML:

```
function mifuncion() {
   alert("hola");
   __doPostBack("Start","miDato");
}
```

En Firefox al pulsar el botón Start me ejecuta la función mifuncion() ya que me muestra el alert con el mensaje hola pero no me llega a hacer el __doPostBack !

Comment: si revisas al developer tool del browser, a la cual accedes con F12, puedes ver en la consola algun mensaje de error en javascript ?

Comment: ¿Podrías explicar lo que quieres hacer? Hace años que dejé webforms y recuerdo un escenario parecido, quizás puedas editar la pregunta, trataré de recordar y tal vez solucionar la pregunta :D

Comment: @LeandroTuttini no tengo ningun error ya que en los otros navegadores funciona perfectamente. Exccepto en Firefox !!

Comment: @fredyfx lo que quiero es que cuando pulse el boton  me haga un postback pero no me hace el postback. En otros navegadores como IE, Chrome, Opera, Edge y navegadores de movil si que funciona !!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Encontré la solución  y es que para Firefox tengo que agregar un "return false;" De tal manera que el código HTML debe quedar así:

```
<button runat="server" onClick='mifuncion(); return false;'>Start</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Intenta usar un botón del ASPnet Webforms y le asignas un `OnClientClick`:

```
<asp:Button OnClientClick="mifuncion();" ClientIDMode="Static" ID="MyButton" runat="server" Text="Start" >
</asp:Button>
```

Javascript:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function mifuncion() {
   alert("hola");
   __doPostBack("Start","miDato");
}

</script>
```

Comment: Tengo que usar controles HTML porque uso html5 y css3.

Comment: ¿Intentaste usar el código mostrado?

Comment: Ya encontré la solución tengo que agregar un "return false;"

Comment: me parece excelente :D

Comment: Gracias !! No tiene mucho sentido pero así funciona para FireFox